# Java inheritance - Two classes that use the same methods

Tags: java, inheritance, casting

I have two classes, `ObjectA` and `ObjectB` that both extend the same class `MasterObject`. I also have an interface which contains a method that I want both `ObjectA` and `ObjectB` to implement. This method is not found within `MasterObject`. I then have a class which has a field of type `MasterObject` and want to access the methods within `ObjectA` and `ObjectB`. Is this possible without casting? Here is some code that I have.

In addition, I am unable to alter the `MasterObject` class.

```
public interface MyInterface{
    void doSomething();
}

class ObjectA extends MasterObject implements MyInterface {

    @Override
    public void doSomething(){
        //...
    }
}

class ObjectB extends MasterObject implements MyInterface {
    @Override 
    public void doSomething(){
        //...
    }
}

class Main {
    MasterObject mObj;

    public void method1() {
        mObj = new ObjectA();
        mObj.doSomething();
    }

    public void method2() {
        mObj = new ObjectB();
        mObj.doSomething(); //runs code from ObjectB class
    }
}
```

Right now this is obviously throwing some compiler issues. (Cannot resolve method doSomething()).

Casting like so: `((ObjectA) mObj).doSomething();` seems to work, but is there another way to do this without casting? Anything cleaner?

Comment: Are you able to alter the `MasterObject` class?

Comment: @CraigR8806 No, I am not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cleanest way would be declaring the object with the interface as type:

```
MyInterface mObj;
```

You can instantiate the object with the concrete classes in the same manner:

```
mObj = new ObjectA();
...
mObj = new ObjectB();
```

The only constraint is that - without casting - you will be able to call only `doSomething` method, since it is the only method defined in the interface. If you intend to use this method only, it is the way to go.

Comment: Thank you. This appears to work. I simplified my problem as much as I could but the truth is that there are several methods shared that I will need to add to the interface.

Answer (score 3):

One final solution would be to create a proxy abstract class `AbstractMasterObject` that implements `MyInterface` this would allow `ObjectA` and `ObjectB` to have full functionality of both `MasterObject` and `MyInterface` if they extend `AbstractMasterObject`

This can be done like so:

```
public abstract class AbstractMasterObject extends MasterObject implements MyInterface{

}
```

Then you could declare your Objects like so:

```
AbstractMasterObject a = new ObjectA();
AbstractMasterObject b = new ObjectB();
```

Comment: proxy is better approach

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the class `MasterObject` doesn't implement the interface `MyInterface`, although his children do.

The solution is to implement the interface:

```
MyInterface mObj;
mObj = new ObjectA();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options here and some have already been mentioned. You've already mentioned that you can't add the interface to `MasterObject` and that the interaction is more complicated than just `doSomething`. Any other constraints will likely determine which is best for you.

The first option is to do like Craig suggested and create the intermediate `AbstractMasterObject` to extend `MasterObject` and implement `MyInterface`. This is a quick and easy way to have a single reference that's both a `MasterObject` and `MyInterface` instance. The downside is that `Main` now has to use `AbstractMasterObject` instead of `MasterObject`. So it can't use any other subclasses of `MasterObject`. That may not be a problem at all or it may be a complete deal-breaker. Realistically, it's somewhere in between.

Another option is to use composition instead of inheritance. So `ObjectA` and `ObjectB` each have an instance of `MasterObject` instead of extending it. Then they use that reference for access to `MasterClass` behavior (For brevity, I'm just showing `ObjectA`):

```
class ObjectA implements MyInterface {

     private masterObject masterObject; 

     public ObjectA(MasterObject masterObject){
       this.masterObject = masterObject;
    }
    @Override
    public void doSomething(){ /* Implementation */ }

 }
```

From here, there are a few different strategies to incorporate this into `Main`. You could have a reference to a `MasterClass` in `Main` and pass that to the `ObjectA` constructor. Then maintain both a `MasterClass` and `MyInterface` reference:

```
class Main {
   MyInterface myInterface;
   MasterObject masterObject;

   public void method1(){
      masterObject = new MasterObject();
      myInterface = new ObjectA(masterObject);

      myInterface.doSomething();
      masterObject.someMasterObjectMethod();

   }
}
```

This approach would only work if `ObjectA` neither overrides `MasterObject` methods nor accesses any protected members. It could also lead to confusion having a reference to the same `MasterObject` in both `Main` and `ObjectA`. If both classes can change the state of `MasterObject` then you might end up with some tricky bugs. On the other hand, if none of these are a concern then this may be a good way. It adds `MyInterface` to `Main` without disrupting `MasterObject` and it uses `MasterObject` indirectly to implement `MyInterface`.

Or you could hide `MasterObject` entirely from `Main` and interact only through `MyInterface`. To do this, you could simply at `getMasterObject` to `MyInterface`. Or you could add methods to `MyInterface` that specifically pertain to how `Main` interacts with it. I think an approach like this is cleanest, but it involves changing the most code. If this is mostly new development, then it may be worth the effort to refactor. If it's older code, then I'd favor a less invasive approach.

Another option approaches this from a slightly different direction. You use the classes exactly as you have them defined. The difference is that `Main` has both a `MasterObject` and `MyInterface` reference pointing to the same instance:

```
class Main {

   private MasterObject masterObject;
   private MyInterface myInterface;

   public void method1(){

       ObjectA objectA = new ObjectA();
       masterObject = objectA; // Legal because ObjectA extends MasterObject
       myInterface = objectA; // Legal because ObjectA implements MyInterface

       myInterface.doSomething(); // This does ObjectA's implementation
       masterObject.someMasterObjectMethod();

   }
}
```

So to `Main`, it's completely coincidental that the same instance performs as `MyInterface` and `MasterObject`. I think this approach would be best if this is legacy code because it's the least invasive. If this is relatively new code, then I'd consider the other strategies before resorting to something like this. There are still other approaches, but I think this should be a good overview. No matter what, you should step back and think about what the relationships among each of these classes really are. That should help point you in the right direction.